# Portably determining whether string is castable to integer

Tags: sql, casting, portability

I'd like to cast a `VARCHAR` to a SQL `INTEGER`, supplying a default value if some value in the field would not convert properly.  Something like:

```
sql> SELECT str FROM tbl;  -- CREATE TABLE tbl (str VARCHAR(12), ...)
    str
========
  12345
     -1
    foo

sql> SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN ... THEN str ELSE '-9999' END) AS INTEGER) AS "int" FROM tbl;
    int
========
  12345
     -1
  -9999
```

What could I put in the ellipsis above to produce the desired results?

This question has been asked and answered on SO for many specific DBs, but I'm wondering if there's a more-or-less portable way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no portable way to do this.

Comment: YOur best bet is to store integer data in integer fields. Do not mix string and integer data together.

Comment: @HLGEM, you're right, of course, but that's not the environment I have.

Comment: @Vadim K., why don't you promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: MIght be time to refactor your current environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the range of values acceptbale for INTEGER (32 bits?  64 bits?) varies from implementation to implementation, there is no non-vendor specific way to do this.

Comment: +1, you raise an excellent consideration.  Let's suppose, however, that INT-size isn't a concern -- say I'm limited to VARCHAR(3) and so won't overflow any actual implementation of INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *nominally portable* approach, using ANSI SQL-99's simple, pseudo-POSIX regexen with the `SIMILAR TO` operator:

```
CAST ((CASE
       WHEN string_column -- in perl:  $string_column =~ /^\s*[+-]?\d+\s*$/
            SIMILAR TO
            '[[:space:]]*([+-]|)[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*'
       THEN
         string_column
       ELSE
         '-9999'         -- default value for un-CASTable strings
       END)
      AS INTEGER
```

I say "nominally portable" because `SIMILAR TO` is not widely supported.  (PostgreSQL has had it for a while, Firebird née Interbase promises it in the upcoming 2.5 release, but that's about it.)